# How to click a Javascript link without ID or name?

Tags: javascript, vbscript, hyperlink, click

Can somebody please show me how to get my VBScript to click a this JavaScript link? I know how to click a link with a `name` or `id` attribute in the HTML, but this one doesn't have ID or name.

Please find the code:

```html
<a href="javascript:addToFilter();"><img src="img/add3.gif" border="0"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over all `<a>` tags and look for the one with that `href` attribute:

```
url = "http://..."

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate url

While ie.ReadyState <> 4
  WScript.Sleep 100
Wend

For Each a In ie.document.getElementsByTagname("a")
  If a.href = "javascript:addToFilter();" Then a.Click
Next
```

For a more intelligent selection you need to provide more context to your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by selecting element via some specific value which element has.

For example, in your example the anchor tag has 'addFilter()' string in href property. So starting from that you make some selector for that.

Plz, check out for selector specification: https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector#Specifications

```html
<a href="javascript:addToFilter();"><img src="img/add3.gif" border="0"></a>
<script>
    var element = document.querySelector("a[href*='addToFilter()']");
    alert(element.outerHTML);
</script>
```